# portd not writing on digital ports 5 and 7

Tags: programming, pins, arduino-leonardo

I try to build a function generator (preferably a sine) with an [R-2R ladder](http://www.auctoris.co.uk/2011/05/25/arduino-function-generator-part-2/) and a [Arduino Leonardo by Borderless Electronics](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/9-arduino-compatible-starter-kit-anyone-can-learn-electronics).

For performance reasons one should use `portd` instead of `digitalWrite`.
However the signal is not at all what I want (just noise). So upon further investigation I found that the digital pins were never on `HIGH`. Pin 6 worked flawlessly. Furthermore I have tested the two failing pins with simple test programms and they behaved exactly as I would have expected.

Here is the code I use

```
 int sine[255];

 void setup() 
 { 
     pinMode(0, OUTPUT); 
     pinMode(1, OUTPUT); 
     pinMode(2, OUTPUT); 
     pinMode(3, OUTPUT); 
     pinMode(4, OUTPUT); 
     pinMode(5, OUTPUT); 
     pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(7, OUTPUT); 

     float x; 
     float y; 
     for(int i=0;i<255;i++)
     {
          x=(float)i;
          y=sin((x/255)*2*PI);
          sine[i]=int(y*128)+128;
     }
} 

void loop() 
{ 
     for (int i=0;i<255;i++) 
     { 
          PORTD=sine[i]; 
          delayMicroseconds(10); 
     }
}
```

I tested this with two Arduinos of the exactly same type.

**Question:** Why are pins 5 and 7 never on `HIGH`?

**Edit:** I have simplified everything down to one statement in the loop: `portd = x;`

I vary x manually

**expected** findings:

x  ->  #pin that is on high

0  -> None

1  -> 0

2  -> 1

4  -> 2

8  -> 3

...

128 -> 7

**actual** findings

x  ->  #pin that is on high

0  ->  None

1  ->  3

2  ->  2

4  ->  0

8  ->  1

16 ->  4

32 ->  None

64 ->  None

128->  6

I test this by simply connecting an oscilloscope to the output pins. The behaviour is extremely strange since the pins seem to be in random order, some even missing to `portd`. Furthermore `portd = B11111111`, according to the manual, is equivalent to `portd = 255;` and should set all pins on `HIGH`. But in my case it sets every pin to `HIGH`, except pins 5 and 7 are on `LOW`.

Comment: How are you testing the signal? Can you give examples of the actual and expected output from all pins?

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks for your comment, i edited the question and hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because on ATmega 32u4, which is used in Arduino Leonardo,  pins 5 and 7 are not mapped to port D but to port C and E respectively, as you can see in the [ATmega 32u4 - Arduino Pin Mapping](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping32u4).

[image]

So you will have to:

- either find another port where all 8 bits are available as digital outputs (note that I'm not sure one such port exists)
- or split each `sine[i]` in 2 parts because you will have to work with 2 ports at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

As @jfpoilpret points out, Arduino pins are not always mapped to port bits in a straightforward manner, and it’s crucial to understand the mapping for your particular model.

In fact, the Arduino Leonardo is designed in a way that **none** of the ports has all 8 bits usable as I/O pins. As far as the microcontroller is concerned, ports B and D each have all 8 bits available, but the Arduino Leonardo/Micro design uses one bit on each port for a LED.

I would also recommend that if you’re using a PORTx register directly, instead of going through the Arduino API, that you also use the DDRx register to set pin directions, instead of trying to use `pinMode`.